# Kotlin typealias with Android Room TypeConverters

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have used Kotlin's typealias to define an E164 phone number type:

```
typealias E164 = String
```

This makes my intention clearer when passing phone numbers around in my code, rather than just passing Strings.  I recognise that there is no actual enforcement of using the correct type, but this works well for me.

Now I want to store an E164 in an Android Room database.  This works without the typealias, but with the typealias it requires a TypeConverters.  I tried this:

```
@Entity data class MyModel(@PrimaryKey val e164: E164, val someOtherThing: String)

class E164Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toE164(value: String): E164 = value

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(e164: E164): String = e164
}
```

The compiler doesn't like the autogenerated Java of the E164Converters class because the toString and toE164 methods both define the same conversion of String -> String.

```
error: Multiple methods define the same conversion. Conflicts with these: CustomTypeConverter(type=E164Converters, method=toString(java.lang.String), from=java.lang.String, to=java.lang.String) public final java.lang.String toE164(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

But if I don't define the TypeConverters, then the compiler doesn't know how to put an E164 in the database:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
private final error.NonExistentClass e164 = null;
```

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `E164Converters`. You can use `E164` as `String`. Like

```
val a: E164 = "blabla"

fun f(x: String) = x
f(a) // compiles
```

I guess you're writing something like

```
fun processPhoneNumber(a: E164) {
  // blabla
}
```

You can invoke the function above like `processPhoneNumber("110")`, which works fine.

You said you get error when using it in

```
@Entity data class MyModel(
  @PrimaryKey val e164: E164,
  val someOtherThing: String
)
```

If I were you I'd consider replace the code above with:

```
data class MyModel private constructor(
  @PrimaryKey val e164: String,
  val someOtherThing: String
) {
  companion object {
    operator fun invoke(e164: E164, someOtherThing: String) =
      MyModel(e164, someOtherThing)
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, but if I change one of the properties in my Room Entity class from String to E164, then the compiler tells me I need to provide a type converter because it doesn't understand how to convert an E164 into something it can put in the database.

Comment: Show me the complete code and where the error message refers to.

Comment: This should be a limitation of annotation processor when working with typealiases. Let me think of a solution for u.

Comment: See my edits. I've made the constructor using `String` and make it private, then created a fake constructor using `E164`. Now the annotation processor will see `String` and the programmer will see `E164`.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  Not as elegant as I would have liked, but I can't see an alternative, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I just ran into this issue, it may already be (mostly) fixed for Room. After I did a full clean/re-build, it was working again with the typealiases.

If it's still not working for you, then I just learned about `ColumnInfo.SQLiteTypeAffinity` to explicitly define how the column is stored.

Here's example usage:

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo.TEXT

typealias FirstName = String

@Entity
class MyEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT) val firstName: FirstName
)
```

More info:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo.SQLiteTypeAffinity
- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#typeAffinity()

  - "The type affinity of the column. This is either UNDEFINED, TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, or BLOB."